# Half-band IIR filter design with cascaded allpass structure

Tags: filter-design, allpass, polyphase

I am trying to design a simple half-band complementary filter bank following [this paper](https://www.academia.edu/15101784/Half_band_IIR_filter_design_using_MATLAB).

I don't have a Matlab license at the moment, so I am trying to implement it in Python, but I'm running into several issues.

The first issue is my calculation of the maximum and minimum cutoff frequencies of the signal. I follow the paper's equations in ***III. A.*** to obtain the maximum Pass-band Edge Frequency, but given the same design constraint I obtain different results than the paper's.

Here is the code I am using:

```py
# Specifications:
fp_spec = 0.22 # Pass band edge
fa_spec = 0.285 # stop band edge
ap_spec = 0.01 # PB ripple in dB
aa_spec = 46 # SP ripple in dB

fp = np.max([fp_spec, 0.5-fa_spec])
fa = 0.5-fp
ap = np.min([ap_spec, 10*np.log10(1+1/(np.power(10, aa_spec/10)-1))])
aa = -10*np.log10(1-np.power(10, -ap/10))

print(f'Fp = {fp:.3f}, Fa = {fa:.3f}, Ap = {ap:.12f} , Aa = {aa:.2f}')
## Until here I am getting correct results)

# Check the minimum order : 
min_order,_ = sp.signal.ellipord(2*fp, 2*fa, ap, aa)
min_order = np.ceil(min_order) // 2 * 2 + 1
print(f'Minimum odd order : N = {int(min_order):d}')

# BELOW IS NOT WORKING.... VALUES DON'T MATCH WITH THE PAPER :'(

ap1 = np.float64(ap_spec)
aa1 = np.float64(aa_spec)
n   = np.float64(int(min_order))

# Elliptic-functions parameters (from https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/55002)
L  = np.power(10, aa1/10) - 1 # 10^aa1/10 - discrimination factor

t  = 1/2 * (1 - np.power(1 - (1/(L**2)), 1/4)) / (1 + np.power(1 - 1/(L**2), 1/4))

q  = t + 2*t**5 + 15*t**9 + 150*t**13

g  = np.exp(np.log(q)/n)

q0 = (g + g**9 + g**25 + g**49 + g**81 + g**121 + g**169) / (1 + 2*(g**4 + g**16 + g**36 + g**64 + g**100 + g**144))

epsilon = 1 / np.sqrt(1 - ((1 - 2*q0)/(1 + 2*q0))**2)

fp1 = 1/np.pi * np.arctan(1/np.sqrt(epsilon))
fa1 = 1/2 - fp1

print(f'Fp,1 = {fp1:.13f} ; Fa,1 = {fa1:.13f}')
```

I am getting $f_{p1} = 0.2166710599539$ where the paper gets $0.216416 ≤ f_p ≤ 0.2343961$ for the same design parameters.

Why am I not getting the same results ? The paper has a few typos here and there and I have to admit the elliptic filter design algebra is a bit beyond my level, so am I making a mistake somewhere in the equations ?

The second blocking point is that there is no equivalent to Matlab's `tf2ca` function in python, and although it seems from the paper that the $\beta_i$ are simply the squared poles' magnitudes I am - again - getting different results from them:

```py
z,p,k = sp.signal.ellip(9, 4.7375787e-6, 59.622281, 2*0.216416, output='zpk')
# parameters copied from the paper's values at fp = fp,min
print(np.sort(np.abs(p[2:6])**2))
```

Gives
`[0.10220591 0.34400767 0.61451422 0.86863355]`

But the paper finds :
$$
0.3197 ≤ β_2 ≤ 0.3914\\
0.5865 ≤ β_3 ≤ 0.6816\\
0.7839 ≤ β_4 ≤ 0.8565\\
0.9320 ≤ β_5 ≤ 0.9593\\
$$

Am I wrong to simply take the square of my TF's poles magnitude?